# boundingRectWithSize sometimes returns height that is about 1 line too tall

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsstring

I have looked at several Stackoverflow questions where people have problems with boundingRectWithSize, but none of them are quite my problem.

The following code often computes a height that is 1 line of text too tall.

```
CGFloat height = [label.attributedText 
   boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(label.width, CGFLOAT_MAX)
   options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading) 
   context:nil].size.height;
```

For example, the string **Map Type: USGS Topo** is about half the width of my view and should be 1-line tall (~18 pixels), but ends up having a 2-line height (~36 pixels):

I also tried calculating the height using the NSString instead of NSAttributedString, but the same thing happens:

```
CGFloat height = [[label.attributedText string] 
    boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(label.width, CGFLOAT_MAX) 
    options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading) 
    attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:TITLE_FONT} 
    context:nil].size.height;
```

You can see in this screenshot that the bottom 3 labels end up sized correctly, but not the top two. I turned on color blended labels in the iOS simulator so the subviews would be colored to illustrate:

[image]

Comment: Not certain that is the cause, but note that the top two strings include characters which are drawn below the baseline (`p` and `y` in the top string, `(` and `)` in the next one) while the other three do not.

Comment: @ravron Yeah, I had noticed that too actually, but I tried changing the below-baseline characters and had the same result.

Comment: Does the issue persist with a standard font? I've had problems with fonts that have wonky values that aren't obvious from looking at them.

Comment: @ravron Yeah, I tried that because of some comments on other SO threads, but I got the same result using a system font:     CGFloat height = [[label.attributedText string] boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(label.width, CGFLOAT_MAX) options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin|NSStringDrawingUsesFontLeading) attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15]} context:nil].size.height;

Comment: Are you sure none of your strings end with a newline?

Comment: @robmayoff That's what it was - thanks so much. If you turn your comment into an answer, I'll accept it. I thought I had tried that before, but I'm now thinking I used stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:
                                                [NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet] when I needed stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet].

Comment: I rolled back your last edit. Don't mark a question as solved. Either post an proper answer or delete the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably have a trailing newline in your string. Try trimming it with `whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet`.

Answer (score 0):

I have had something similar happen to me awhile ago, though it was not with an attributed string. When it happened to me the lable's frame wasn't fully set yet and so at the time of the calculation the width was narrow enough that it had to wrap to the next line. Check the frame for your label when you do this calculation and make sure it is actually as wide as you think it is.